# How to effectively generate Spark dataset filled with random values?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I need a `Dataset<Double>` of arbitrary size filled with random or generated values.

It seems it can be done by implementing `RDD`, and generating values inside `compute` method.
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Random Data Generation`

- sql functions to generate columns filled with random values
- Two supported distributions: uniform and normal
- Useful for randomized algorithms, prototyping and performance testing

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{rand, randn}

val dfr = sqlContext.range(0,10) // range can be what you want
val randomValues = dfr.select("id")
                      .withColumn("uniform", rand(10L))
                      .withColumn("normal", randn(10L))

randomValues.show(truncate = false)
```

output

```
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
|id |uniform            |normal              |
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
|0  |0.41371264720975787|-0.5877482396744728 |
|1  |0.7311719281896606 |1.5746327759749246  |
|2  |0.1982919638208397 |-0.256535324205377  |
|3  |0.12714181165849525|-0.31703264334668824|
|4  |0.7604318153406678 |0.4977629425313746  |
|5  |0.12030715258495939|-0.506853671746243  |
|6  |0.12131363910425985|1.4250903895905769  |
|7  |0.44292918521277047|-0.1413699193557902 |
|8  |0.8898784253886249 |0.9657665088756656  |
|9  |0.03650707717266999|-0.5021009082343131 |
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps you, but have a look -

```scala
   val end = 100 // change this as required
    val ds = spark.sql(s"select value from values (sequence(0, $end)) T(value)")
      .selectExpr("explode(value) as value").selectExpr("(value * rand()) value")
      .as(Encoders.DOUBLE)

    ds.show(false)
    ds.printSchema()
    /**
      * +-------------------+
      * |value              |
      * +-------------------+
      * |0.0                |
      * |0.6598598027815629 |
      * |0.34305452447822704|
      * |0.2421654251914631 |
      * |3.1937041196518896 |
      * |0.9120972627613766 |
      * |3.307431250924596  |
      *
      * root
      * |-- value: double (nullable = false)
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it,

```
scala> val ds = spark.range(100)
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> val randDS = ds.withColumn("randomDouble", rand(100)).drop("id").as[Double]
randDS: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Double] = [randomDouble: double]

scala> randDS.show
+--------------------+
|        randomDouble|
+--------------------+
|  0.6841403791584381|
| 0.21180593775249568|
|0.020396922902442105|
|  0.3372830927732784|
|   0.967636350481069|
|  0.6420539234134518|
| 0.33027994655769854|
|  0.8027165538297113|
|  0.9938809031700999|
|  0.8346083871437393|
| 0.13512419677124388|
|0.061866246009553594|
|  0.5243597971107068|
| 0.38257478262291045|
|  0.6753627729921755|
|  0.9631590027671125|
| 0.14234112716353464|
| 0.38649575105988976|
|  0.7687994020915501|
|  0.8436272154312096|
+--------------------+
```